# How can I open gthumb maximized?

Tags: maximized, gthumb

Is there a way to open images with gthumb using the full width and height of the screen? I mean to open them maximized. Now when I click on an image it always opens filling 1/4 of the screen.

When i click on image and open it now, it opens like this:

[image: small image window]

When I actually want to open gthumb maximized like this:

[image: gthumb window fills screen]

Now I need to click maximize every time I open an image.

Comment: Mine seems to remember my last window size. At first it opens up halfway and I then maximize it. From there it always open maximized.

Answer (score 1):

If you open gthumb options through its menu, **Edit > Preferences**, you'll find a tab called "visualization" or something similar (I don't know the exact name, because my installation is not in English).

There, you can chose how to open new images, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: gthumb settings]

Comment: This is to open images in full resolution, i am searching to open gthumb in maximized mode, not images. BTW your theme looks amazing what's the name of the theme?

Comment: OK, so you want the window, not the image maximized... Sorry I missunderstood. Can't point you to the exact answer but you can achieve that trough configuring compiz windows rules, with ccsm compizconfig-settings-manager. The theme is called darkenza, and I intalled it from a PPA from webupd8. I don't have the address right now but searching "darkenza theme webupd8" or something like that should point you in the right direction.